# Python Plots - Loop through unique values of a feature and plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a feature in my pandas data frame which can take on (potentially) several levels. I can obtain the unique levels using the following:

`reasons = df["Reason"].unique()`

I can plot a the counts of all the levels on a single graph doing the following:

`for reason in reasons:
    df[df['Reason']== reason].groupby('date').count()['twp'].plot()
    plt.title(reason)
    plt.tight_layout()`

How can I modify this code so that it can create a separate graph for each level? Furthermore, I would want ensure scalability as well. (For example if the number of unique levels is currently 3, but in the future we can end up with 5 levels).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post your DataFrame?

Comment: Try looking for `subplots`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bazingaa mentioned, use subplots:

```
reasons = df["Reason"].unique()
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(reasons), 1) 

for reason, ax in zip(reasons, axes):
    df[df['Reason']== reason].groupby('date').count()['twp'].plot(ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(reason)

plt.tight_layout()
```